# Spring EL adding operator to expression through a variable

Tags: java, spring, parsing, el, spring-el

I have a value to be evaluated according to a set of values(in a list) through Spring EL. Currently if I'm doing as follows it gives me the correct answer

```
ArrayList<Condition> list2 = (ArrayList) parser.parseExpression("#list.?[15 gt new Integer(value)]").getValue(context)
```

but if I replace 'gt' with a bean variable it gives me an error, for this I'm having the following bean class

```
public class Condition {
    private String condition;//This will be having values like 'gt' 'lt' etc.
    private String value;//Value to be evalate agaist 
    private String path;//What should be done
//geter setter will be here
}
```

With this if I'm to parse this as follows it gives me following error. Please advice.

```
ArrayList<Condition> list2 = (ArrayList) parser.parseExpression("#list.?[15 condition new Integer(value)]").getValue(context)
```

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos
>   12): Unexpected token.  Expected 'rsquare(])' but was 'identifier'